# KnockoutJS: how to get foreach row selector for jQuery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

i'm quite new here but this site helped me a lot already, so I hope you guys can help with a question of my own.

I just started out with coding with KnockoutJS and I like it so far, it's very different way of programming for me but I already see the advantages it gives me.

But, I am running into a little problem, which probably is really simple but I just can't get it done.

I stripped down my code to pinpoint the problem here.

I have a list which gets generated by the foreach binding in KO but when I click on it I want a jQuery event to happen, in this case for example I want it to hide with an animation.

As you see in the code I could just simply write some lines at the bottom of the script in a dom-ready function and hardcode the jquery event for al li elements in the ul, but because of the fact I chose (among other reasons) to code in KO to tidy op my code for larger projects I really want to write the jquery event which happens when a user clicks on the li in to click binding.

Here is my code and for convenience I've made a jfiddle too:
http://jsfiddle.net/edleutscher/JTa5Y/

JS:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.people = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Bert' },
        { name: 'Charles' },
        { name: 'Denise' }
    ]);

    self.clickAction = function(data) {
        $(data).hide();
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());​
```

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'rowTemplate', foreach: people }"></ul>

<script type="text/html" id="rowTemplate">
<li data-bind="click: function() { $root.clickAction($data) }">${name}</li>
</script>​
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the event to the click function so you can have access to the element that was clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/JTa5Y/1/

Your click function:

```
self.clickAction = function(data, event) {
    $(event.target).hide();
}
```

And the data bind statement

```
<script type="text/html" id="rowTemplate">
    <li data-bind="click: function(vm, event) { $root.clickAction($data, event) }">${name}</li>
</script>​
```

Comment: That just works perfect, i knew it must be something simple. Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: It's better to bind it as "click: clickAction.bind($data)" and remove the ugly code block from your view.